# Jquery .on() method

Tags: jquery

I want to allow to click on my buttons on conditions. So I use the .on() method to allow to click just when the class "clickable" is present.  :

```
$(".button").on("click", ".clickable", function () { 
  alert("click");
});

$("#stop").click( function () {
  $(".button").removeClass('clickable');
});
```

But I can't click on my buttons from the beginning. 
Is my .on() method not correct ?

this my html structure :

```
<div class="button clickable">1</div>
<div class="button clickable">2</div> 
<div class="button clickable">3</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: please show your HTML structure so that we can better understand how the events are supposed to be bound.

Comment: first the buttons are clickable and then I want to manage it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I am making the following assumption about the HTML structure:

```
<someelement class="button clickable"></someelement>
```

It sounds like you may be adding/removing elements to the page, or simply changing the selection of active buttons, you should use the `delegate` or `live` form of `on` using a parent node as the base selector. The simplest to use is `document`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.button.clickable', function () {...});
```

the selector in the second parameter has to be a *descendant* of the first selector (in this case, `$(document)`).

---

If you, instead, called:

```
$('.button.clickable').on('click', function () {...});
```

and then removed the `clickable` class (assume `#foo` is one of the buttons):

```
$('#foo').removeClass('clickable')
```

you'd still fire the event listener when you click on the button, because the event was bound directly on every element in the matched set.

Comment: The simplest and most horrible option is to use document as the listener. There is almost always a better ancestor. zzzzBov has no way of knowing what that ancestor is (hence the 'document' suggestion) but I have no doubt you can find one. Still upvoting.

Comment: @GregPettit, it's the same as using `live` (which is deprecated in favor of this form) and is quite responsive.

Comment: @zzzzBov - `.live()` is exactly why I argue that it's a bad choice. It's long been considered poor practice to use it; a better practice has been until now to use `.delegate()` with a proper listener. @Maxxx - at least use the `.on()` suggestion even if exactly as zzzzBov presents it.... unless you're stuck with something less than jQuery 1.7. He mentioned `.live()` because that's what his code reproduces... but it's a deprecated function!

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".button").on("click", ".clickable", function () { 
    alert("click");
});
```

The meaning of this is that clicking on any element with the class name of `clickable` which is WITHIN an element with a class of `.button`.

I think you want anything with both a class of `button` and `clickable` in which case it should be this:

```
$(".button.clickable").on("click", function () { 
    alert("click");
});
```

Comment: I'm not going to downvote you because you've got a reasonable suggestion, but the events will remain bound to the elements if the classes on the elements change.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow click only when the button has class `clickable` then use this code. I am assuming our button has `button` class in it.

```
$(".button.clickable").on("click", function () { 
    alert("click");
});
```