# jQuery click function only working once (a tag)

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, click

I have gone thought stackoverflow for a solution to my jQuery click function only firing once on the same page load and noticed that the solutions provided only apply to specific element referencing.

My jQuery listens for a tag request (`<a href=...>`)
So does anyone know how to make my listener fire multiple times while listening to this type of tag?

Current Code

```
$("a").click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('href') != '#' && $(this).attr('href') != '#myModal'){
        displayLoader();
    }
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463959/jquery-click-function-only-working-once-new-situation?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if($(this).attr('href') != '#' && $(this).attr('href') != '#myModal'){
        displayLoader();
    }
}
```

ev.preventDefault() will prevent the default behavior of the click, and proceed with the custom code that you had create, you can find more explanation here http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: Answers with just a code block and no explanation generally get flagged for deletion.  I would add some details as to how your code solves the problem!

Comment: I thought the same thing. it is also essentially the same as the first answer provided.

Answer (score 0):

"a" tags default event is it will process the link(href) when clicked. So you need to prevent that by=

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     //rest of the codes to handle the click
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
  $("a").on("click",function() {
if($(this).attr('href') != '#' && $(this).attr('href') != '#myModal'){
    displayLoader();
   }
 }
```